# when I click on the button the url is changed but the page is not and i have to refresh the page to go to the new page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom 4.0.0. when I click on the button the url is changed but the page is not and i have to refresh the page to go to the new page.

```
  render() {         
        return (             
                <div className='text-xs-right' >
                    <Link to="/posts/new" >
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" > Add a Post </button>
                    </Link>
                </div>                   
        );
    }
```

and this is my Router:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import promise from 'redux-promise';


import reducers from './reducers';
import PostsIndex from './components/postsIndex';
import NewPost from './components/newPost';


const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route exact path={'/'} component={PostsIndex} />
        <Route exact path={'/posts/new'} component={NewPost} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

and this is my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-redux": "4.3.0",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3"
  }
```

i found a solution but still don't know why my previous code didn't work. the code below worked though:

```
 <Switch>
    <Route path={'/posts/new'} component={NewPost} />
    <Route path={'/'} component={PostsIndex} />
  </Switch>
```

why didn't my first approach work?

Answer (score 0):

ok found a solution, I just needed to update my packages to:

```
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
```

and now this work properly without any need to refresh the page:

```
<Router>
      <div>
          <Route exact path={'/'} component={PostsIndex} />
          <Route exact path={'/posts/new'} component={NewPost} />
      </div>
    </Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why that happens is `Switch` matches the first match it finds to match the Route. In your case, when `/` was above `/posts/new` what happened was `/` also matched `/posts/new` so it rendered `/` and didn't check for the remaining. When you put it in reversing order, when the link was `/posts/new` it first matched it and didn't check for `/` so you got it correct.

Alternatively you can pass `exact` prop so that it will match the link only if it is exact. Then you can write

```
 <Switch>
   <Route path={'/'} exact component={PostsIndex} />
   <Route path={'/posts/new'} component={NewPost} />
  </Switch>
```

Now `/` will be matched only if the link is exactly `/` and so you will get the result you expected.

Let the path be `/one` and `location.pathname` be `/one/two`. If exact is false, the path `/one` will match `/one/two`, whereas if exact is true it will not.

Comment: my main question is that why when i used <Router>
      <div>
        <Route exact path={'/'} component={PostsIndex} />
        <Route exact path={'/posts/new'} component={NewPost} />
      </div>
    </Router>  after clicking on the button the url change but the page didn't an di had to refresh the page

Comment: The reason is the path `/posts/new` also matches `/`. So it will render '/'. go to https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md and read the heading **exact: bool**

Comment: but if you notice i put `exact` there so the exact path will match